# What is the scope for third party subpoenas in civil litigation?

Tags: united-states, evidence, civil-procedure

Are third party subpoena's of large organizations allowed in civil litigation?

For example, if there is a lawsuit over a business deal, can one or more of the parties subpoena phone records such as emails and text messages from a phone company or an email provider? Also, what about internet service providers such as Google and Facebook? For example, if there is say a defamation lawsuit about something posted to Facebook, can the plaintiff subpoena Facebook to get records concerning when and what things were posted there?

Answer (score 5):

A party may subpoena materials from a nonparty using a subpoena under [Rule 45](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_45).

A party may generally subpoena anything that is within the scope of discovery under Rule 26, i.e., any material that is [relevant](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/relevant#:%7E:text=Relevant%20means%2C%20with%20regards%20to,fact%20significant%20to%20the%20case.), not [privileged](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/privilege), and [proportional to the needs of the case](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/litigation/committees/pretrial-practice-discovery/practice/2019/proportionality-has-some-bite/).

Rule 45 also protects third parties from subpoenas that impose an "undue burden," but I would argue that this is essentially the same thing as Rule 26's proportionality requirement.

Records of phone calls, e-mails, and text messages are routinely subject to subpoenas under Rule 45, but again, that assumes that the messages are relevant and not privileged.

Records to Facebook and Google can be a bit more complicated. I don't know that the question has actually been definitively answered, but social-media companies seem to take the position that access to certain records created by their users is exempt from subpoena under the [Stored Communications Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2701).

Comment: I would suggest that social media companies lose more contests of subpoenas than they win on that ground.

Comment: This is excellent news. If you've seen any good cases analyzing the weaknesses in that objection, I'd love to see them.